# Why does BoundedExecutor have to catch RejectedExecutionException?

Tags: java, concurrency, executor

As to BoundedExecutor in the book Java Concurrency in Practice, task submission has been throttled by semaphore. When would the underlying executor throw a RejectedExecutionException? Maybe when operating system runs out of threads?

```
public class BoundedExecutor {
  private final Executor exec;
  private final Semaphore semaphore;

  public BoundedExecutor(Executor exec, int bound) {
    this.exec = exec;
    this.semaphore = new Semaphore(bound);
  }

  public void submitTask(final Runnable command) throws InterruptedException, RejectedExecutionException 
  {
    semaphore.acquire();

    try {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    command.run();
                } finally {
                    semaphore.release();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        semaphore.release();
        throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the contract of [`Executor.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-) is that it can throw a [`RejectedExecutionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html):

> if this task cannot be accepted for execution

What that means for any given `Executor` implementation is up to the discretion of that implementation. I could create an `OnlyOnSundaysExecutor` that rejects tasks unless the current day of the week is Sunday. You would have to check the documentation for the various `Executor` implementations to see under what circumstances they would throw a `RejectedExecutionException` exception.

Comment: Or when the underlying executor has been shutdown, it will not accept the task.

Comment: @mnemonics, `Executor`s have no concept of being shutdown. You might be thinking of an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the circumstances under which an exception might be thrown, it is important to keep your application in a consistent state, even when exceptions occur.

Here, the semaphore that has been acquired should always get released. For most resources that should get released under all circumstances, you would use a `try {} finally { /* release action */ }` construct to ensure the release even in the exceptional case, but here, we have the special situation that the release action should be performed *only* in the exceptional case, as in the successful case, the submitted `Runnable` will perform the release action (note that within the `Runnable`, `finally` is indeed being used).

So the code is supposed to handle the case when a `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown. We might want to do that for every `RuntimeException` or `Error`, but the problem is, `RejectedExecutionException` is the only exception type where we know for sure that the runnable will never get executed. For all other kinds of exceptions, it is possible that it will still run.

To make the cleanup safe, you would need another atomic toggle:

```
public void submitTask(final Runnable command) throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicBoolean proceed = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    semaphore.acquire();
    try {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                if(proceed.compareAndSet(true, false)) try {
                    command.run();
                } finally {
                    semaphore.release();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(Throwable e) {
        if(proceed.compareAndSet(true, false)) semaphore.release();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Now, in every exceptional case, an attempt to release the semaphore will be made, unless the `Runnable` flagged that it is already running. Or the `Runnable` will not proceed if it detects that the semaphore has been released due to an exception in the submitting code.

This is, of course, more complicated than the book example and possibly distracting from the original intent of the example. Also, it uses the Java 7 feature of being able to easily catch and re-throw all possible exceptions of the `try` block. This wasn’t available when the book was written.